# project http to https url change problems

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-10

I have a WCF service-based project using .net framework 4.8.

I configured my project to use https instead of http. The project is working properly but we are getting the error below on IIS 10 startup.

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
```

Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/21647132
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/ProposalService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
Process Name: w3wp
Process ID: 29208

Answer (score 0):

Please do the below steps

- Go to control panel
- open Turn windows feature on/off
- .net frame work 4.8 advance serviced
- check WCF Services as attached
  [Steps to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzNGc.png)

Hope this will work for you if not please share more details

Comment: This thing really helps IIS to deploy WCF services. I might also mention two things that might help: 1.Is the **web.config** file on your IIS the same as the **web.config** file on your service? 2. Change the port.